# Java classloader getResource fails after time

Tags: java, websphere, classloader

I'm loading a resource file which is included in the root folder of my jar file:

```
URL schema = JsonObject.class.getClassLoader().getResource("document-schema.json");

if(schema == null){
    throw new IllegalStateException()
}

// do stuff with the file...
```

The jar, which *does* include my schema is then deployed into a Websphere Application server and executed. The code runs multiple times a day. However, after ~24-48 hours it starts failing with the IllegalStateException i.e. returns `null` for `getResource()`.

Reloading the jar makes it work again for another day or so. (And then the cycle repeats)

I cannot fathom why I wouldn't be able to load my own internal resources after a while. Is there a mechanic that a classloader deregisters resources after a while?

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: The only obvious thing that would "deregister" a resource/jar would be if the application is restarted, which clears out the class loader and creates a new instance. If you're holding onto the old class loader beyond that restart, the loads after that restart would fail - unlike class loads, getResource results are not cached. My first check would be for an unexpected app/module restart, which could be triggered by an application class path change - automatic app reloading is enabled by default.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue, since I'm always getting the currently valid ClassLoader if I do `MyClass.class.getClassLoader()` right? Maybe I can find something in the logs...

Comment: That's not correct. In Jarid's suggestion, you may essentially have two application class loaders for the same app - the "old" (leaked) loader and the new loader. When you leak a classloader, all of the classes it loaded are also leaked - so you could be using the leaked class instance of `MyClass` which would return you the leaked instance of the classloader.  That leaked instance would likely fail with ISEs, etc. To test this hypothesis, you could get a heap dump after it occurs and see how many app class loaders are in the heap compared to how many apps/modules are in use. HTH

Comment: Yeah, what Andy said... the most common way to do that is if your application creates its own thread - if the thread doesn't get deleted when the app stops, then it'll continue existing, complete with references to classes from a dead class loader (and probably a reference to the loader as well, as its thread context loader). Note, of course, that all of this is moot if there's no app restart in play here.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This is a bit above my skill-level to debug on my own. Luckily there are no application restarts involved as far as I can tell. Maybe I can circumvent it some other way, perhaps by restarting the application server during the night. Ugly, but would get the issue out of my hair...